# How do you make an image blink?

Tags: html, css, image, blink

I was wondering how to make an image blink in CSS, if it is possible. I want to have it blink where it is.

I would also like to change the speed but mainly I want to make it blink.

Comment: Don't think it's possible with just CSS but you could do it with Javascript.

Comment: Could you explain "blink" a little more? Do you want to brighten the image for a instant, or turn it white, or a different color?

Comment: There's a reason the `<blink>` tag died a horrible death you know.

Comment: You can use CSS Animations and keyframes for this, but that might be a bit overkill for a simple blink.

Answer (score 59):

CSS animations to the rescue!

```
@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
img {
    animation: blink 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r6dje/

You can make it a sharp blink by adjusting the intervals:

```
@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    49% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtJF5/1/

Comment: If i hover, image wont blink. Any option?

Comment: This is great, but it also needs code for Chrome browsers as well.

Comment: You need also add cross-browser compability rules for `keyframes` (like `-moz-keyframes`, `-webkit-keyframes` etc.), `animation-iteration-count` (like `-moz-animation-iteration-count`, `-webkit-animation-iteration-count` etc.) and `animation` (`-moz-animation`, `-webkit-animation` etc).

Answer (score 1):

use setInterval method of Javascript use it as a reference of [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval1) and then change the css from `visibility:visible` to `visiblity:hidden` we will not use `display:none` as it will remove the space of the image as well but we do need the space for the image for the blinking thing to work.

Comment: BTW please create a formal account on SO. It is really helpful. Thanks. I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS easily. Just add below cross browser code in the CSS element of your image. You can set also timing if you change the digit in the code.

```
-webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation:blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out; 
-ms-animation:blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out; 
animation:blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out;
```